# Joint distributions where each RV "makes an equal contribution"

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If I draw $k$ balls from an urn without replacement, I have dependent random variables $(Y_1, \dotsc, Y_k)$. Suppose for concreteness that the $Y_i$ take values in a finite set of colors, or can take the value $\underline{\texttt{empty}}$ if there are no balls left in the urn.

These variables have an interesting property that the distribution can't tell the difference between the ones that happened first, second, third (as long as I don't run out of balls). We can see this by noting that we could just as easily think about drawing them all at once.

So for instance

1. The marginals $Y_i \overset{d}{=}Y_j$ for all $i,j$, and
2. $P(Y_{i_1} \mid Y_{i_2}, \dotsc, Y_{i_r})$ is the same for all $i_1 \neq \dotsb \neq i_r$.

(These properties cease to hold if I choose $k$ greater than the total number of balls in the urn: then the last variables are deterministic, with the value $\underline{\texttt{empty}}$.)

I'd want to call these "distributions where each variable makes an equal contribution" or something. What is the modern formulation of this? (I can imagine it might be useful to subsume it in another concept, or perhaps break apart these properties further.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the usual term is "exchangeable random varibles".  The wikipedia [aricle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables) will give you a hint about the range of connotations associated with this term, so you might not want to use it,
but I think it includes most of what you describe.